# Creating XNA AudioEngine on windows game project

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, xact

I'm reading this book "Learning XNA 4.0", and in chapter 6 it teaches how to play sounds using XACT Audio files. It asks me to create an AudioEngine object, but I can't find that class.[AudioEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.audioengine%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx)

I have the right using statement (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio) and the right reference (microsoft.xna.framework.dll).

does anybody have any idea whats wrong?

Comment: theres nothing to show, I just started a  new project, and cant find the AudioEngine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an error in the documentation. `AudioEngine` is actually in the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact` assembly. Add a reference to that, and everything should work as expected.

Note that XACT is not available on Windows Phone 7 (this is why it is in a separate assembly). If you plan to go mobile later, use `SoundEffect` instead.