# XNA 4.0 cannot create an AudioEngine

Tags: audio, xna-4.0, xact

This question is a derivative of this one: [Creating XNA AudioEngine on windows game project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389044/creating-xna-audioengine-on-windows-game-project)

I am working from the same book, and have the same problem as the original question. The solution provided by Andrew doesn't work as doesn't exist as well.

I am unable to use `AudioEngine` class in my project. I have tried adding this using statement:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact;
```

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have the **reference** to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact.dll`

In Visual Studio, in your Game project, right click on **References** folder -> **Add Reference**

Select **Browse** tab, and navigate to Program Files (x86)/Microsoft XNA/XNA Game Sudio/v4.0/References/Windows/x86/, select **Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact.dll** and click on **OK**.

Add `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;` and you should be able to use `AudioEngine` class.

Comment: Wow there it is!! Thank you so much!