# XNA cannot create an AudioEngine

Tags: audio, xna, xact

Referencing this Question/Answer (and many others like it): [XNA 4.0 cannot create an AudioEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307898/xna-4-0-cannot-create-an-audioengine/29835351?noredirect=1#comment47798159_29835351)

I cannot seem to get this to work. Any help would be super appreciated as the  solution linked is NOT working for me and I've googled a lot about this and everything seems to reference the same solution. I know how to add references and have done them successfully in the past, and I additionally have the correct using statements at the top so I'm not really sure what is going wrong, but AudioEngine will not show up for me. If anyone can help I would really appreciate it, thanks!

(I don't have enough reputation to post images yet, so here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJeul.png)

This is all that shows up when I start to type "Audio..." https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTnQ9.png

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is happening because I'm trying to make a Windows 4.0 game. I tried making an Xbox 4.0 game and adding the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact.dll reference and AudioEngine shows up just fine.

Does AudioEngine/Xact not work with Windows 4.0 games or is there something I'm missing?